# Merging multiple text files into one using R

Tags: r

I am trying to merge multiple text files into a csv and have done it successfully using the following code. I have one additional requirement, I need to add the name of the file in a separate column indicating where the data came from. Please suggest.

rm

```
(list=ls())
setwd("D:/Cersai Rejection Reasons/IT_Oct18-Jun19")
file_list <- list.files()
df <- data.frame(file_list)

library(plyr)   
library(dplyr)

files <- dir("D:/Cersai Rejection Reasons/IT_Oct18-Jun19", 
             full.names = TRUE)
df <- lapply(files, function(x) 
  read.table(x, sep = '\t', header = FALSE)) %>% 
  plyr::ldply() 
write.csv(df, file="D:/consolidatetext.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- lapply(files, function(x) {
  df <- read.table(x, sep = '\t', header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df$source <- x
  return(df)
}) %>%
  bind_rows()

write.csv(df, file="D:/consolidatetext.csv")
```

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote,  ... :
  EOF within quoted string
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
4: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :

Comment: Total 38 such warnings

Comment: The `EOF` warning shouldn't be important but you could check if all files are in the final `df` and check what is wrong with the files that are not in `df`. The factor level warning can be circumvent by using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (see updated answer)

Comment: Ah I misread the `EOF` warning. That one is important. You can try `readr::read_tsv(x)` instead of  `read.table` on the files that have the problem. Otherwise you have to tinker with the quote characters.

Comment: @SANYAM - don't forget to check as answered.